# Chocolatey Passing array as a parameter

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

Can someone advice how to pass array as parameter to chocolatey package. I have written below sample code to test the code.

```
$pp = Get-PackageParameters

# set a default if it not passed
if (!$pp['PowerUser']) { "Provide user to proceed further."}


Foreach ($user in $pp['PowerUser']) {
    "$user"
}
```

I am using below command to run the package:

```
choco install -f .\amm.test.install.1.0.nupkg --params "/PowerUser:Test1,Test2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably - given that Chocolatey doesn't know anything about the purpose of the open-ended pass-through parameters passed to its `--params` parameter - the *string* `Test1,Test2` is stored as-is in `$pp['PowerUser']`.

Therefore, it is up to you to interpret the string as an *array*, which you can do with the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator:

```
foreach ($user in $pp['PowerUser'] -split ',') {
  $user
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. It is working for me. Thank you so much.